# jQuery Validate immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I've not seen an answer on SO, nor in the validation plugin documentation.

I have a form with inputs that need validation. When the page loads, I call `$('#my-form').validate()`.

The problem is, my inputs only get validated after the first modification + `blur()` event. I would like the validator to **validate the inputs and display error messages before the first user interaction** (on page load).

The only way I found so far is to `focus()` and `blur()` all my inputs on page load, but the form is quite big and this causes the page to scroll down.

Comment: By default, validation is "lazy", you want validation to be "eager".

Comment: Please note the second bullet point here in the documentation:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-a-few-things-to-look-out-for-when-playing-around-with-the-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you're done setting up the form, run

```
$('#my-form').valid()
```

This validates the form, as well as return a boolean with the validation result.

[Documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/)

Comment: Only the first input gets validated when I do this. All inputs are inside the form, have different ids, have the `required` attribute and some are empty (that should trigger a validation error). What am I missing ?

Comment: Can you put together a jsfiddle of it? And what versions are you using of jQuery and jQueryValidate?

Comment: @Heru-Luin, that makes no sense.  When you attach `.valid()` to the form, the entire form is validated at once.

Comment: @Cernael My bad, there was another error in the code. When I fixed it, your solution worked.
Thanks.